# Load multiple images from mongodb/nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on a nodejs, express, jade project.

I have a route/template that display 20 images. Those images are extracted from a mongodb database.

Some images are not displayed on the browser. If I manually click on those images in the browser, it works. I have had some log and I see that the 8 images are not called by the browser. So I do not think it is a mongodb problem. Is there a limitation somewhere in nodejs?

Comment: Usually, big binary files are not directly stored in mongodb. Rather, you put them in other servers like [imgur](https://api.imgur.com/), and then store the links in mongodb. Maybe your html rendered from jade is wrong. Use dev tools of your favorite browser to check the Network and see how many image requests are made.

Comment: I have checked With Safari Dev tools and i have a red error message. If i copy paste image url in à new tab it works

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Comment: It is a french version of safari. The message is "une erreur s'est produite lors de la tentative de chargement de la resource".
In fact i am wondering if i need to configure something or make some tuning when putting a nodejs application in production